# Can values be too small/big for pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

So i've got the following code, in which I want to extraplorate a linear regression line. My attempt was to add `\pgfplotstableregressiona*x+\pgfplotstableregressionb` as a new plot, but it simply won't show a graph. I used [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205577/pgfplots-extending-a-regression-line-beyond-the-tables-points) as reference.

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            height=0.75*\textwidth,
            title=$E_{kin}$-$f$-Diagramm,
            grid=major,
            xlabel={$f$ in \si{\hertz}},% \SI{10e14}{Hz}},
            ylabel={$E_{kin}=e\cdot U$ in \si{\electronvolt}},
            legend pos = north west
            ]
            \addplot [only marks, black] table [
            x = ft,
            y = et,
            ] {
            ft  et
            490658687397709 1.4419589706E-17
            509851119047619 2.95334559534E-17
            571033253333333 7.09230189984E-17
            593648431683168 8.03224552512E-17
            635153512711864 1.108706230728E-16
            };
            \addplot [blue] table [ %draw=none
                x = ft,
                y = {create col/linear regression={y=et}},
            ]{
            ft  et
            490658687397709 1.4419589706E-17
            509851119047619 2.95334559534E-17
            571033253333333 7.09230189984E-17
            593648431683168 8.03224552512E-17
            635153512711864 1.108706230728E-16
            };
            \addlegendentry{$E_{kin}(f)$}
            \addlegendentry{
            $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona}\cdot x
            \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
            \addplot[no marks,red]{\pgfplotstableregressiona*x+\pgfplotstableregressionb};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces:[image: Output]
So as you see, it will only draw the line which is directly produced by the linear regression but not the extended one i want to have, even if the code is similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205577/pgfplots-extending-a-regression-line-beyond-the-tables-points) solution. My suggestion is, that the used values are too small or big to be handled by the package.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just solved this: I needed to add domain values in the final regression line plot like this: `\addplot[no marks, red, domain=0:7*10^14]{\pgfplotstableregressiona*x+\pgfplotstableregressionb};` manually, but now it works.

**Hope this helps someone with the same problem.**