# How can I extend the line here (extrapolate)?

Tags: pgfplots

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%Paragraph jumps and indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

%Border
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
%Double spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\doublespacing
%Packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{times} 
\newfloat{chart}{tbph}{loc}
\floatname{chart}{Graph}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\di}{i}          
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%Images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
%Tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

%Equation numbering
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\urlstyle{same}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]

    \centering
    
    \begin {tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
       Price (AED) & \# of carpet customers\\
        \hline
        434 (current mean price) & 150 \\
        \hline
       477.4 (10\% higher) & 140\\
       \hline
        651(50\% higher) & 126\\
       \hline
       868 (100\% higher) & 103\\
        \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

Using table 4's data, the demand curve shown below was created to represent customers' willingness and ability to purchase a carpet at different prices.

\begin{chart}[H]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
            width=\linewidth,
        }
\begin{axis}[
    error bars/x dir=both,
    error bars/y dir=both,
    error bars/x explicit,
    error bars/y explicit,
    xlabel={Quantity ( \# of customers)},
    ylabel={Single Carpet Price (AED)},
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200},
    ytick={0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900},
    legend pos=south east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    xmin=0, xmax=200,
    ymin=0, ymax=900,
    ]
    
    \addplot [
        only marks,
        mark=o,
        ] 
    table [
        x=x,
        y=y,
        ] {
        x   y
        150 434
        140 477.4
        126 651
        103 868
        };
    
    \addplot[
        black,
        empty legend
        ] 
    table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
    X   Y
    150 434
    140 477.4
    126 651
    103 868
    };
    \addplot[domain=0:200, samples=2]{\pgfplotstableregressiona*x+\pgfplotstableregressionb}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{chart}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @dexteritas, is that better? I am new so Im not sure which packages are needed to do this so I just put all of mine.

Comment: Welcome! Now the formatting is better, but your code is still not minimal at all. You should try to create an example with the minimum number of packages, with a simpler graph, and then explain better what you want to extrapolate and where...

Comment: You can try the method described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205577/pgfplots-extending-a-regression-line-beyond-the-tables-points

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I dont quite get what they did after reading it, do you mind helping me?

Comment: The slope and intercept of the regression is stored in the two macros you see in that answer, so you can use those to plot a straight line over whatever domain you want, e.g. `\addplot[domain=0:200, samples=2]{\pgfplotstableregressiona*x+\pgfplotstableregressionb};` after your existing `\addplot` that makes the linear regression.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., for some reason the code doesnt work still. I edited my original question to incorporate your comment (the \addplot) but it shows an error.

Comment: You forgot the `;` at the end. (I first get two other errors that has nothing to do with the plot though, one from using `\newfloat` before loading the `float` package, and one from the fact that you're defining `\tabitem` twice.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It works!!! thank you so much. Just one last thing, is it possible to remove the top line and right line. Right now, the graph is in a box but I just want the x and y axis to be blacked. Not sure if I communicated that well

Comment: `axis lines=left` in the `axis`  options?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. im sorry im very new to this, hwo can i find where the axis options are? 

Nevermind, I got it, thank you very much!